# how to configure servlet in web xml

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to Java and trying to learn Servlet. I have created Servlet class as "config" inside the package database. now i need to update same in web.xml as

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>config</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/config</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But it is not working?
Any help appreciated!!

Comment: What's your servlet look like?What is its package and what error is raised by server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably your servlet is in a package:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>my.package.config</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rename it to `ConfigServlet` to adhere to the naming conventions, and use the fully qualified name `database.ConfigServlet` in your web.xml.

You should also look into package naming conventions as well. Having a package named "database" is weird, especially if you have a servlet in there.

Answer (score 0):

In  the :

```
<servlet-class>config</servlet-class>
```

you have to put whole servlet class name. It contains name of the package and the name of the class. Something like `com.mycompany.MyServlet`:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>config</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mycompany.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```